# Should this question be rolled back and closed because it didn't show code?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, specific-question

The [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1155/18427).

The reason: we have had discussions before about not editing in code because of licensing, and that adding any code must be done by the OP and not someone else, same with reviewing third party code.

The [question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/18427) where the discussion took place.

All the answers on the question are relevant here, but I think that [svick's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/974/18427) says the most.

Comment: The discussion took place in 2012, while the question you linked to is from 2011. So it's hard to blame the person who edited the question in this case.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what license pastebin enforces. Is "anyone" allowed to take it and use it "anywhere"? If that is the case, then if another user edits the question and adds the code there is no harm done, right?

Comment: I am not blaming the editor, I just don't want someone to see questions and edits like that and think it is ok.  leading by example type of thing,  it should have been fixed after that discussion.

Comment: @Malachi: If you find any more of these questions, feel free to rollback and vote to close (it'll still appear on the queue, and it doesn't necessarily warrant immediate closure by a moderator).

Comment: @Jamal I wasn't sure about this situation because it was a Moderator that did it and the OP hasn't signed up for a Code Review account.  but I will just do it and not worry about consequences.  I think that I have a good idea of how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reverted the changes, closed the question, and left a comment.  While I do agree with @Simon, I don't think it matters either way since it's an old question.  However, that in mind, I *probably* would've kept it as is if the link was broken.

Comment: for links that are broken there is a site that I have seen other mods use, it's called something like archive or something,  I would ask around.  it links to a version of the site closest to the time it was there or something.